# Keep checkboxes checked when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have the following form with checkboxes.

```
<?php
   include 'connection.php';
   $sql="SELECT * FROM `tbl`";
   $query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
   echo "<table border='2px'>
             <thead>
                 <th>ID</th>
                 <th>Title</th>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Doing</th>
                 <th>Done</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <form method='POST'>";
                      while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                          $id=$res['id'];
                          echo"<tr>
                                  <td>{$res['id']}</td>
                                  <td>{$res['title']}</td>
                                  <td>{$res['name']}</td>
                                  <td><input type='checkbox' name='doing[]' value='".$res['id'].$res['title'].$res['name']."'></td>
                                  <td><input type='checkbox' name='done[]' value='".$res['id'].$res['title'].$res['name']."'></td>
                               </tr>";
                      }
                      echo "<input type='submit' value='OK' name='btn'>
                 </form>
             </tbody>
         </table>";
?>
```

How do I make the checkboxes keep their `checked` state when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't want both `doing` and `done` to be checked at the same time, so I replaced the checkboxes with radio buttons because that is their intended behavior.

I changed the names and values for the radio buttons so that they can be easily accessed in PHP, and from the code you've supplied it doesn't look appear as if you're using the names and values afterwards anyways.

I cleaned up the markup and script layout to make it more readable.

Please let me know if I have deviated too far from the intent of your original code.

<sup>**Note:** This will *display* the posted values, but it will not *save* those values to the database.</sup>

([Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/3hka-7htq))

```
<?php
    include('connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl`";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    function get_checked ( $id ) {
        if ( isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['checked'][$id]) ) {
            return $_POST['checked'][$id];
        }
        return false;
    }
?>
<form method="post">
    <table border="2px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Doing</th>
                <th>Done</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ( $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $query ) ): ?>
                <?php $checked = get_checked ( $res['id'] ) ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $res['id'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $res['title'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $res['name'] ?></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="checked[<?= $res['id'] ?>]" value="doing" <?= $checked === "doing" ? 'checked' : '' ?>></td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="checked[<?= $res['id'] ?>]" value="done" <?= $checked === "done" ? 'checked' : '' ?>></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='OK' name='btn'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this code.Hope this will work (Also try to use mysqli or PDO):

```
<?php
         include 'connection.php';
         $sql="SELECT * FROM `tbl`";
         $query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

            echo "<table border='2px'>
      <thead>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Doing</th>
      <th>Done</th>
       </thead>";
         echo "<form method='POST'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        $s=0;
        while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id=$res['id'];
        $doing_v="";
        $done_v="";
        $c_doing="";
        $c_done="";

        if(isset($_POST['doing'][$s])){
        $doing_v=$_POST['doing'][$s];
        }

        if(isset($_POST['done'][$s])){
        $done_v=$_POST['done'][$s];
        }

        if($doing_v=='".$res['id'].$res['title'].$res['name']."'){
        $c_doing="checked";
        }

        if($done_v=='".$res['id'].$res['title'].$res['name']."'){
        $c_done="checked";
        }

              echo" <td>{$res['id']}</td>
               <td>{$res['title']}</td>
               <td>{$res['name']}</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='doing[]'
        value='".$res['id'].$res['title'].$res['name']."' ".$c_doing." ></td>

               <td><input type='checkbox' name='done[]'  
         value='".$res['id'].$res['title'].$res['name']."' ".$c_done." ></td>
               </tr>";
               $s++;
               }

               echo "</table>";
               echo "<input type='submit' value='OK' name='btn'>";
               echo "</form>";
          ?>
```